# test service with promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple `service` that queries an `api` to fetch some data using `promises` for the `controllers`. I want to test services alone using `jasmine`. However, the services are dependent on some constants that I inject to get the `api urls`.

Here is how the service is defined:

```
angular.module('dbRequest', [])
  .factory('Request', ['$http', 'localConfig', function($http, localConfig){
    return {
      getRevision: function(){
          return $http({
            url: localConfig.data,
            method: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
          })
      }
}]);
```

`localConfig` is defined as constants in `app.js`. Following [this tutorial](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/comprehensive-guide-to-unit-testing-in-angularjs), here is how I am testing the service:

```
describe('Service: Request', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('webApp'));

  var reqService, $q, $scope, lc;

  beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function($injector){
      reqService = $injector.get('Request');
      $q = $injector.get('$q');
      lc = $injector.get('localConfig');
      $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    });
  });

  it('should test service definition', function(done){
    expect(reqService).toBeDefined();
    done();
  });

  it('should get db revision', function(done){
    spyOn(reqService, ['getRevision']).and.returnValue($q.when({/*what comes here??*/}));
    reqService.getRevision().then(function(res){
      expect(res.length).toBe(1);
      done();
    });
    $scope.$digest();
  });
});
```

I need to test whether the length of the data returned from the api (which is an array) is greater than 0. Which determines if the test passes in this case. This poses 2 problems here:

- How to inject constants in the `service`?
- How to test the response?

My response looks like this:

```
data: ["option1", "option2"]
```